# c++ library for parsing packets with winpcap

Tags: c++, winpcap, libpcap

is there a c++ opensource library for parsing capturing packets with winpcap specificly the tcp header and data ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adapt the source code of Wireshark or tcpdump. Both are open source.

Answer (score 1):

There is **[`libpacketdump`](https://wand.net.nz/trac/libtrace/browser/libpacketdump)** which is part of the libtrace networking suite.

According to it's makers, it is

> libpacketdump provides decoders to dump the contents of packets in human
>   readable form

Be sure to check the license (I haven't)

### Project webpage

http://www.wand.net.nz/trac/libtrace/